# Is there a PHP function to call all variables from a form?

Tags: php, forms, text, input, variables

Hey, I'm programming a feedback form on a website for a client, however, there are over 100 inputs (all uniquely named). I was wondering if there was a loop I could run to get all of the variables, do you have to call them like this:

```
$variable = $_REQUEST['variable'];
```

EDIT:

I'm going with $_POST as recommended by everyone here - thanks for the input! I'll just manually go through and write a line for each $_POST I have.

Comment: Don't use REQUEST, use POST if they are posted, and GET if they are from the URL. Seriously. You should never, ever, ever use REQUEST.

Comment: What specifically are you doing this for? Why does one form even have 100 unique inputs? There may be a better solution. I tend to always handle form fields individually because I require different sanity checks for each field, but I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over all veriables in the $_PREQUEST array:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value){
  //doStuff
}
```

However this will include all send parameters, not only the input. Also you should not use $_REQUEST but $_POST or $_GET

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to have hundreds of uniquely named variables and want to have arrays of data turn up client side, there is a handy form trick you may want to try.

```
<form>
  <input name="foo[a]" type="text" />
  <input name="foo[b]" type="text" />
  <input name="bar[]" type="text"  />
  <input name="bar[]" type="text"  />
```

Client Side:

```
<?php
   $_POST['foo']['a']; 
   $_POST['foo']['b'];
   $_POST['bar'][0];
   $_POST['bar'][1];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST); // or $_GET
echo "</pre>";
```

If you are dealing with items that you possibly won't know the name of but need the values then you are dealing with a much larger problem than you think.

But the above snippet should show you all variables set and their values when you submit the form

Comment: Useful to know for the OP, but won't help you actually do anything with them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start out with a list of all variables that you expect, and loop only over those. If you don't, hackers can inject *any* variable name... In fact, you're reemplementing the old, terribly bad idea of [Register Globals](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/Register_Globals). So, don't do that...

In fact, why not keep the input in an associative array, just like $_POST? You might still want to remove those values that you didn't expect.

Answer (score 0):

The [`$_GET`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [`$_POST`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array variables contain every parameter passed via URL or POST method respectively. You should rather use that variables instead of extracting every item like the [`register_globals` option](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) or [`extract` function](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) does. See [Using Register Globals](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) for the reasons.

Comment: You might want to clarify that register globals is *NEVER* a good idea. For *any* reason. People who *think* its a good idea end up writing security holes under the guise of a website.

Answer (score 0):

As in my comment above, don't use REQUEST, use POST. I'd probably write a line for each one so that I was aware of what was happening. You don't want people to post extra variables that still get parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple code to algorithmically obtain all inputs from a posted form, but this is a dangerous business, one that is ripe for exploitation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment on Pim Jager's post, but here's an example code:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    echo($key.' > '.$value.'<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array with the fields you want copied from POST and store the data in an array. It's a lot easier to maintain.

```
$fields = array("name","email","addr","bla","bla2");
$form = array();
foreach($fields as $field){
    $form[$field] = $_POST[$field];
}
```

Now you've got all the data inside `$form`.
You could also make a similar thing when creating the form. (Although it's trickier..)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            ${$key} = $value;
    }
```

but this does the same thing as extract()